# How to escape column names with hyphen in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have imported a json file in Spark and convertd it into a table as

```
myDF.registerTempTable("myDF")
```

I then want to run SQL queries on this resulting table

```
val newTable = sqlContext.sql("select column-1 from myDF")
```

However this gives me an error because of the hypen in the name of the column `column-1`. How do I resolve this is Spark SQL?

Comment: Try escaping them with single quotes sqlContext.sql("select 'column-1' from myDF")

Comment: That does not work because it will treat 'column-1' as a string not a column name.

Comment: The SQL-99 standard specifies that double quote (") is used to delimit identifiers. Try them with double quotes maybe keeping the outer ones in single quotes

Comment: run query as `"""select "column-1" from myDF"""`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Backticks (`) appear to work, so

```
val newTable = sqlContext.sql("select `column-1` from myDF")
```

should do the trick, at least in Spark v1.3.x.

Answer (score 4):

Was at it for a bit yesterday, turns out there is a way to escape the (:) and a (.) like so:

Only the field containing (:) needs to be escaped with backticks

```
sqlc.select("select `sn2:AnyAddRq`.AnyInfo.noInfo.someRef.myInfo.someData.Name AS sn2_AnyAddRq_AnyInfo_noInfo_someRef_myInfo_someData_Name from masterTable").show()
```

Comment: This works for columns having spaces as well, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment as I have less than 50 reps

When you are referencing a json structure with struct.struct.field and there is a namespace present like:

ns2:struct.struct.field the backticks(`) does not work.

```
jsonDF = sqlc.read.load('jsonMsgs', format="json")
jsonDF.registerTempTable("masterTable")
sqlc.select("select `sn2:AnyAddRq.AnyInfo.noInfo.someRef.myInfo.someData.Name` AS sn2_AnyAddRq_AnyInfo_noInfo_someRef_myInfo_someData_Name from masterTable").show()
```

pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '`sn2:AnyAddRq.AnyInfo.noInfo.someRef.myInfo.someData.Name`'

If I remove the sn2: fields, the query executes.

I have also tried with single quote ('), backslash (\) and double quotes("")

The only way it works if if I register another temp table on the sn2: strucutre, I am able access the fields within it like so

```
anotherDF = jsonDF.select("sn2:AnyAddRq.AnyInfo.noInfo.someRef.myInfo.someData")
anotherDF.registerTempTable("anotherDF")
sqlc.select("select Name from anotherDF").show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do, which also works in `Spark 3.x`.

I define function `litCol()` at the top of my program (or in some `global scope`):

```
litCols = lambda seq: ','.join(('`'+x+'`' for x in seq)) # Accepts any sequence of strings.
```

And then apply it as necessary to prepare my literalized `SELECT` columns. Here's an example:

```
>>> UNPROTECTED_COLS = ["RegionName", "StateName", "2012-01", "2012-02"]
>>> LITERALIZED_COLS = litCols(UNPROTECTED_COLS)
>>> print(LITERALIZED_COLS)
`RegionName`,`StateName`,`2012-01`,`2012-02`
```

The problematic `column names` in this example are the `YYYY-MM` columns, which `Spark` will resolve as an expression, resulting in `2011` and `2010`, respectively.