# How to deal with dash with SQL request in SparkContext

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I use this SQL request in a spark context:

```
SELECT Max(F-Measure) FROM fMeasure_table
```

And I get the Exception:
[image]

Comment: Delimit it as `"F-measure"`.

Comment: Delimit it with backtick (`) character, like this: `F-Measure`

Answer (score 0):

To select a column with hyphen `-` in Apache Spark use following syntax:

For Apache Spark 1.x or below:

```
sqlContext.sql("select max(`F-Measure`) from fMeasure_table")
```

For Apache Spark 2.x or above:

```
spark.sql("select max(`F-Measure`) from fMeasure_table")
```

Here is the link for a similar question: [How to escape column names with hyphen in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889630/how-to-escape-column-names-with-hyphen-in-spark-sql)