# Spark: cannot resolve input columns

Tags: apache-spark

I have

```
val colNames = data.schema.fieldNames
.filter(colName => colName.split("-")(0) == "20003" || colName == "eid")
```

which I then use to select a subset of a dataframe:

```
var medData = data.select(colNames.map(c => col(c)): _*).rdd
```

but I get

```
cannot resolve '`20003-0.0`' given input columns: 
[20003-0.0, 20003-0.1, 20003-0.2, 20003-0.3];;
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 4):

I had to include backticks like this:

```
var medData = data.select(colNames.map(c => col(s"`$c`")): _*).rdd
```

spark is for some reason adding the backticks

Comment: Hey cosmos1990, any idea why this is happening? I just came up against the same thing and can't fathom why this might be happening

Comment: Looks like its not spark adding the back-ticks, but rather the back-ticks being required to escape the dots and hyphens - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18502 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889630/how-to-escape-column-names-with-hyphen-in-spark-sql